# What is WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, macros, c-preprocessor, windows-10

I was looking through Microsoft's port of OpenSSL on GitHub. One commit caught my eye, and it was [Adding Win10 Universal Platform support](http://github.com/Microsoft/openssl/commit/3e8a22c4c880cad92f36aa29f0c75d118e11f362). In the commit, a partition called `WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP` showed up. However, I'm not finding much about it when searching. There are two hits in English and 22 hits in Chinese (see below).

Following [What’s new in Visual Studio Tools for Windows 10 Preview](https://jiangsheng.net/2015/03/24/whats-new-in-visual-studio-tools-for-windows-10-preview/) provides some quasi-bullet points with no explanations:

- new API partition WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP
- ARM 64
- Universal CRT
- ...

I have two questions:

- What is `WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP`, and how is it intended to be used?
- Can I use `WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP` to [detect Aarch64/ARM64 on Windows 10 gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37244202/608639)?

---

Here's Microsoft's use of it in OpenSSL ([snipped from `ssl/dtls1.h`](https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl/commit/3e8a22c4c880cad92f36aa29f0c75d118e11f362); the C++ comment was moved above the define for readability):

```
// winsock.h not present in WindowsPhone/WindowsStore, defining the expected struct here 
#if defined(WINAPI_FAMILY) && ( WINAPI_FAMILY==WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP || WINAPI_FAMILY==WINAPI_FAMILY_PC_APP || WINAPI_FAMILY==WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP)
    struct next_timeout {
        long tv_sec;
        long tv_usec;
} next_timeout;
```

---

[image]

Comment: is the question answered with my reply or not?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is API which are available to [all windows platforms (mobile, PC, xbox, hololens, IoT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn927350(v=vs.85).aspx).

> **Windows OneCore**
>
> Windows OneCore is a platform for any device—phone, tablet, desktop,
>   or IoT. Windows 10 provides a set of API and DDI interfaces that are
>   common to multiple editions of Windows 10. This set of interfaces is
>   called OneCore. With OneCore, you can also be assured that drivers and
>   apps that are created using OneCore interfaces will run on multiple
>   devices.